# How can I return a result set with the values of a field as column headers?

Tags: mysql

Here's a rough idea of what I have:

```
+---------------+   +-----------------+    +---------------+
| customers     |   | transactions    |    | branches      |
+---------------+   +-----------------+    +---------------+
| customerid    |   | orderid         |    | branchid      |
|               |   | customerid (FK) |    |               | 
|               |   | branchid (FK)   |    |               | 
+---------------+   | datetime        |    +---------------+
                    +-----------------+
```

How would I create a query which pulls in the count of transactions per day/week/etc. but for each branchid **separately**?

I have tried an union such as this (count for all Saturdays only). Which gives a result but not in the format desired.

```
SELECT COUNT(orderid) as count1 FROM transactions WHERE WEEKDAY(datetime) = 5 
AND branchid = 'branch1' 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(orderid) as count2 FROM transactions WHERE WEEKDAY(datetime) = 5 
AND branchid = 'branch2'
```

returns:

```
+------------+
|   count1   |
+------------+
|        152 |
|         48 |
+------------+
```

Whereas I would like the data to be formatted as follows:

```
+------------+------------+
|   count1   |   count2   |
+------------+------------+
|        152 |         48 |
|            |            |
+------------+------------+
```

Does anyone have any hints on how this can be done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this. Using the `UNION` you already have, you can build a pivot query around a subquery.  This version adds a static `name` to each of the columns in your original UNION and uses them to differentiate a `CASE` statement on the outer query.

In your case, it could be done with subselects inside the `SELECT` list, however this method is more extensible to other kinds of pivot queries and is the more general convention for achieving them.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'count1' THEN counts ELSE 0 END) AS count1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'count2' THEN counts ELSE 0 END) AS count2
FROM (
   SELECT 'count1' as name, COUNT(orderid) as counts FROM transactions WHERE WEEKDAY(datetime) = 5 
     AND branchid = 'branch1' 
   UNION 
   SELECT 'count2' as name, COUNT(orderid) as counts FROM transactions WHERE WEEKDAY(datetime) = 5 
     AND branchid = 'branch2'
) subq
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  This is sort of along the lines I was referencing.  Similar idea.

Comment: Thank you for this, I wasn't aware that something like this existed. Very useful!

Answer (score 2):

It is strange that you want it as columns and not rows but I believe this should do what you require:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(orderid) as count1 FROM transactions WHERE WEEKDAY(datetime) = 5 
AND branchid = 'branch1'),
(SELECT COUNT(orderid) as count1 FROM transactions WHERE WEEKDAY(datetime) = 5 
AND branchid = 'branch2')
```

Comment: I'm aware it's a bit awkward - the reason I would like them as columns is because there are charts generated from the table (with each column as a different line). Thank you for your suggestion.. I don't know why I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 1):

In the SELECT section, use a CASE and check if it is branch1 or branch2.  You can define separate columns for each in the SELECT.  And you don't need to do a UNION -- you can do a GROUP BY branchid WHERE branchid in ('branch1','branch2').  Make sense?

Comment: Thanks Dweiss - both you and Michael did a nice explanation.